# How to use the Xquery function fn:parse-ietf-date with a Google timestamp?

Tags: xml, timestamp, xquery, flwor, ietf

It looks like this [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65342726/4531180) function chokes on the string which Google provides.  For example:

```
Saturday, 2 December 2017 at 15:00:32 UTC
```

doesn't seem to parse, at least using the basex console with this function:

```
> 
> xquery fn:parse-ietf-date("Wed, 6 Jun 94 07:29:35 GMT") 
1994-06-06T07:29:35Z
Query executed in 0.82 ms.
> 
> xquery fn:parse-ietf-date("Sat, 2 December 2017 15:00:32 UTC") 
Stopped at ., 1/19:
[FORG0010] Invalid input ('-' expected, 'e' found): 'Sat, 2 December 2017 15:00:32 UTC'.
> xquery fn:parse-ietf-date("Sat, 2 Dec 2017 15:00:32 UTC") 
2017-12-02T15:00:32Z
Query executed in 3.45 ms.
> 
> xquery fn:parse-ietf-date("Sat, 2 Dec 2017 at 15:00:32 UTC") 
Stopped at ., 1/19:
[FORG0010] Invalid input (time expected, 'a' found): 'Sat, 2 Dec 2017 at 15:00:32 UTC'.
> 
> xquery fn:parse-ietf-date("Sat, 2 December 2017 15:00:32 UTC") 
Stopped at ., 1/19:
[FORG0010] Invalid input ('-' expected, 'e' found): 'Sat, 2 December 2017 15:00:32 UTC'.
>
```

It looks like "at" causes havoc, as does a full month versus just an abbreviated month.

is this function able to parse this date?  If not, what alternate function might be suitable?

Presumably Google's using a [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34040048/4531180) timestamp.

(data [originates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65342726/4531180) from "google hangouts" exported as JSON.)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I will try it, but almost certainly.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the [grammar](https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/parse-ietf-date.html) of `fn:parse-ietf-date()` you notice not only the at but also the written out month is throwing the parser off; you could fix this using `fn:replace()` with a a regex like that:

```
parse-ietf-date(
  replace('Saturday, 2 December 2017 at 15:00:32 UTC', 
        '(\w+, \d+ [A-z]\w\w)\w+ (\d{4}) at',
        '$1 $2'
  )
)
```

[Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=&=&extract=parse-ietf-date(%0A%20%20replace(%27Saturday%2C%202%20December%202017%20at%2015%3A00%3A32%20UTC%27%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27(%5Cw%2B%2C%20%5Cd%2B%20%5BA-z%5D%5Cw%5Cw)%5Cw%2B%20(%5Cd%7B4%7D)%20at%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%241%20%242%27%0A%20%20)%0A)&=parse-ietf-date(%0A%20%20replace(%27Saturday%2C%202%20December%202017%20at%2015%3A00%3A32%20UTC%27%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27(%5Cw%2B%2C%20%5Cd%2B%20%5BA-z%5D%5Cw%5Cw)%5Cw%2B%20(%5Cd%7B4%7D)%20at%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27%241%20%242%27%0A%20%20)%0A)&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)